# C# released project : project.exe doesn't do anything

Tags: console, c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a Console Application C# project, it runs fine in Debug mode, and I released it. The .exe file it created located in bin\release doesn't seem to work, it just changes my cursor to an arrow and hourglass in the explorer window. I also can't see the task in the task manager.

I don't know if a Console Application is supposed to show or hide the console by default, so maybe it's just that, but I couldn't find anything on google.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community, and Discord.Net libraries.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try running it in a console window. It is likely crashing due to an dependency or environment issue, and it happens too quick to see. Also, check your event log for the time period in question.

Comment: In debug mode, as a Window Application, it works, but I can't see the Console, even when using a Console.WriteLine() . Also, where can I find the event log ? I'm sorry, it's the first program I try to release.
What I am trying to do is to be able to run the program, he does stuff, I monitor him with the console, and I can close it with the console.

Comment: That is the question for StackOverflow. It's off-topic here. Change your project properties to be linked as Console application or Allocate console on your first line in main().